# javascript Short Code embed external content into website

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, embed

I'm working on a site and i kinda hit a brick wall. Here is what im trying to do.

I have a php script that will run some queries on my site.

What I need to be able to do is let people that visit my site to be able to copy a "short code" (for the lack of a better word) and display content on there site with a simple short javascript code. Not all these sites will be on my web server. I found a sample of what I'm trying to do....

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://www.biblegateway.com/votd/votd.write.callback.js"> 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://www.biblegateway.com/votd/get?format=json&version=KJV&callback=BG.votdWriteCallback"> 
</script>
```

How can I make this display content on a users site based off my mysql results?
I have no idea where to start. All I know is I can not use AJAX.

Comment: The _language_ attribute of `<script>` is _depreciated_.

Comment: Your question is also a little vague, where are you encountering a problem? mysql queries? mysql result -> json? json -> jsonp? interpreting the json in javascript after you've passed it?

Comment: Sorry paul. I dont know what i need yo do or how to go about it. I need the code as short as possible (a copy and past version ) of a long drawn out code. I just dont know how to do this i know mysql but thats as far as i know about this

Answer (score 0):

http://www.biblegateway.com/votd/get?format=json&version=KJV&callback=BG.votdWriteCallback  is NOT a script file

Params of a functions are useable in javascript.

use a library to connect data base with javascript.  jQuery ?? please google.